# How to embed a paginated report in react

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am facing difficulties setting my react application to embed a paginated Power BI report. I can get it working fine on a normal report but I am unable to do it on a paginated report.

I am new to embedding the power BI paginated report in react app if anyone has an example of react code they use to render the paginated report inside their react web application?

I have searched through all the documentation and I might be missing some simple config.

Here's what I have tried so far:

In **App.jsx**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  service,
  factories,
  models
} from 'powerbi-client';

const powerbi = new service.Service(
  factories.hpmFactory,
  factories.wpmpFactory,
  factories.routerFactory
);

const App = () => {
  const reportContainerRef = useRef(null);


  useEffect(() => {
    const reportContainer = reportContainerRef.current;

    const report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, {
      type: 'report',
      tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
      accessToken: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE',
      embedUrl:'EMBED_URL_HERE',
      settings: {
        filterPaneEnabled: false,
        navContentPanelEnabled: true
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-full">
      <div className="flex items-center h-full w-full" ref={reportContainerRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I didn't know how I could get the access token from the Power BI REST API but for now, I have copied via the console of the paginated report that needs to be shown using the command **copy(powerBIAccessToken)**.

For Embed URL - I have got it by clicking on File > Embed in the paginated report.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but in my react app I am just getting spinner and the report is not getting loaded. I am getting the below error in the console but I am not able to pinpoint if this is the exact issue:
[image]

I am not able to figure out why it is behaving this way. Is there a way to achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Embed Power BI Paginated reports requires service principal.
To get the Access token, Refer to React Developer Samples GitHub repo [PowerBI-Developer-Samples/React-TS](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/React-TS)

Follow the readme file to setup the App if you are facing any issues

References:

[Embed paginated reports in your Power BI embedded analytics application - Power BI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-paginated-reports?tabs=customers)

Comment: just a question I am using the App owns data approach to embed paginated reports in our react SPA. And the sample github repo is using the User Owns data approach. Is there a much difference between both of them? I am new to this so wanted to understand it better.